# Any way to get instagram business profiles contact number using unofficial instagram api or scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

There are lot of apis that allows to scrape business profile email but I can't find anything that can scrape business profile contact number. I think the main reason would be contact option is available only in instagram app.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the "Unofficial APIs", talking about ***scraping***.

---

**Instagram treats all accounts the same**, there is **no easy way** to filter business accounts(via URL for example).
what you can try is **first scrape the list followers/following** of some big player(Popular Account) of your domain for which you want the accounts for, then **loop threw each of them**
via

---

**[https://www.instagram.com/[Account](https://www.instagram.com/%5BAccount) user-id scraped]/**

---

then for each, you can **check if it's a business account**(look for the **special HTML thing which you find only on business accounts or any other**).